# Windows cmd stderr redirection to stdout while keeping output to stderr?

Tags: windows, redirection, windows-command-prompt, stdout, stderr

Is there a way in Windows 7 cmd shell to redirect the stderr to stdout while keeping the stderr stream intact?

For example, I have a program that outputs to stderr and stdout the following message

```
TO STDOUT  
TO STDERR
```

I want to have two files stderr.txt and stdout.txt with the following content

> **stderr.txt**
>   TO STDERR
>
> **stdout.txt**
>   TO STDOUT
>   TO STDERR

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
dir a.txt > output.msg 2> output.err >&1
```

or

```
dir 1>a.txt 2>&1 | type a.txt
```

`2>` redirects *stderr*
`&1` sends *stderr* back to *stderr*.

I'd have to test these to give you a better answer

Comment: The first is not working. The second redirects stderr to stdout but does not give stderr alone.

Comment: may need to use a tee clone. The tricky part is that you want 2 copies of stderr.  Pity you are stuck in the legacy prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This is kludgy, but it works.  clip.exe comes with modern versions of Windows and you can download it's counterpart - paste.exe - from several sources.

This line assumes that the file yyz.pdq does not exist and will therefore produce a "File Not Found" message to stderr:

`(dir yyz.pdq 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) | clip & paste >con & paste >err.txt`

This form of the command will redirect to separate files for stderr and stdout+stderr, as originally requested:

`((dir yyz.pdq 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) | clip & paste & paste >err.txt) 1>out.txt 2>&1`